# How to pass data from django to d3.js

Tags: django, d3.js

I'm doing a survey web project at the moment that requires me to use d3.js to perform some kind of bar chart visualization. I'm using Django to program my web application.

The problem I encounter is how do I pass all values related to an object into an array that is used in d3.js?

```
choice = question.choicelist.get(choice_no=choice_no)
```

where votes for each choices to the question will be choice 1 = 4, choice 2 = 6, choice 3 = 7, choice 4 = 1.

For ds.js, the most simplest way to read a data set is:

```
var data = [ 4, 6, 7, 1]
```

How do I pass the data to my template such that d3.js is able to read it as the code above?

Answer (score 8):

Handiest option: convert it to json. Json is valid javascript, so you can insert it directly into the template, which seems to be what you want. Something like

```
import json

def your_view(request):
    poll_results = [4, 6, 7, 1]
    poll_as_json = json.dumps(poll_results)
    # Gives you a string '[4, 6, 7, 1]'
    ...
    return render_or_whatever(context={'poll_as_json': poll_as_json})
```

And in your template:

```
<script ...>
   var data = {{ poll_as_json }};
   ...
</script>
```

Something like that?

Comment: Hmm, as poll_results is always changing, there is no way I can set it as a fixed array. Is there a way for me to put in those values by calling an object using .all()?

Comment: Yes. Exactly how to do it depends on your data model, of course. Django might be able to help you do the aggregating/counting directly in your database query. Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/ for ideas. Dummy example for inspiration: `Answer.objects.annotate(num_votes=Count('vote'))` could give you all answers with an extra `num_votes` field containing the number of votes. Just an example though, you'll have to try it out with your own models.

Comment: @U.f.O, I had a similar question and ReinoutvanRees' answer worked out.  If it worked out for you too, can you accept this answer so others in the future know it worked?  Thanks!